# Add a command to VisualStudio's Debug menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I want to create a VisualStudio extension that adds a command to the Debug menu. The template contains the following line:

```
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
```

which adds the button to the tools menu. Sadly I can't figure out how to change that line, so that the button will appear in the Debug menu.

According to this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx there is no such thing as a debug menu :-/

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e68d90a-b569-4821-b87b-b48122b32bee/adding-a-menu-item-to-the-debug-menu?forum=vsx

Comment: Uhh, why does this need to be so comlicated? Anyway, this works :-) Could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quote from here: [Adding a menu item to the Debug menu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e68d90a-b569-4821-b87b-b48122b32bee/adding-a-menu-item-to-the-debug-menu?forum=vsx)

> Debug menu does not in the GUID guidSHLMainMenu, but in GUID
>   guidVSDebugGroup. And there is no IDM_VS_MENU_DEBUG ID, replace it
>   with IDM_DEBUG_MENU as following:
>
> Don't forget to reference VSDbgCmd.h and VsDebugGuids.h in your VSCT.

Comment: But Where in the Debug menu does it appear, exactly? I see mine appearing in the general/right click on the toolbar context menu, but not in the actual Debug menu.

Comment: you need to add a menu group first and then add your menu inside that